Java: GZIP file contains another GZIP file when saving logs in Windows
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to download log files from a mock service and save them as GZIP files on a Windows system. However, I've encountered an issue where the saved .gz file contains another .gz file inside it, which is not the intended behavior.
Problem Description
When I retrieve the log data from the service and save it as a .gz file, the resulting file at C:\sgtw\downInternal\system.log-2024-07-21-1721500200.gz contains another GZIP file with the same name inside it. This inner GZIP file, when extracted, contains the actual log data.
Expected Behavior
I want the log data to be saved directly in the GZIP file without any nested structure. The final output should be a single .gz file containing the log data directly.
Code Snippet
Here’s the relevant part of my controller code:
    @Controller 
   public class MyController {
    
    @PostMapping("/download-logs")
    public String downloadLogs(@RequestParam List<String> entryCheckbox,
                                @RequestParam String token,
                                @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams,
                                Model model) {
    
        System.out.println("Inside downloadLogs method of controller");
        System.out.println("Token value is: " + token);
    
        List<String> successfullyDownloadedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    
        // Check if any log files are selected
        if (entryCheckbox.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "No log files selected for download.");
            return "downloaded_sgtw"; // Redirect to a result page with an error
        }
    
        try {
            String ids = String.join(",", entryCheckbox);
            byte[] logData = sgtwService.fetchLogsFromMockService(ids, token.replace("Bearer ", ""));
    
            // Check if the fetched log data is valid
            if (logData == null || logData.length == 0) {
                model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "No log data retrieved. Please check the selected log files.");
                return "downloaded_sgtw"; // Redirect to a result page with an error
            }
    
            // Retrieve the log name from the request parameters which should include the .gz extension
            String logName = allRequestParams.get("logName_" + entryCheckbox.get(0));
            if (logName == null || !logName.endsWith(".gz")) {
                model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid log name. Ensure it includes the .gz extension.");
                return "downloaded_sgtw"; // Redirect to a result page with an error
            }
    
            // Specify the directory where you want to save the file
            String destinationDir = "C:\\sgtw\\downInternal";
            String destinationPath = Paths.get(destinationDir, logName).toString(); // Use the log name directly
    
            System.out.println("Destination Path: " + destinationPath);
            System.out.println("Log data byte array length: " + logData.length);
    
            // Write the log data directly to the file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath)) {
                fileOutputStream.write(logData); // Write the byte array directly
            } // Automatically closes the stream here
    
            successfullyDownloadedFiles.add(logName);
            // Processing for success messages
            model.addAttribute("successMessage", "Logs saved successfully at: " + destinationPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Error occurred while downloading logs: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    
        return "downloaded_sgtw"; // Redirect to the result page
    }
    }

Additional Information

I'm running the application on a Windows environment.
The expected output is a single .gz file containing the log data, but instead, I receive a nested .gz file structure.

Question
How can I modify my implementation to ensure that the log data is saved directly in the GZIP file without any nested GZIP files? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Conceptually it's pretty straightforward but first I want to ask you why you are reading your zipped data into memory when presumably the origin can produce something of quite a large size?

The second thing one has to ask is why the entity is being zipped twice since the second zipping is almost certainly going to produce a storage size that's larger than the first? If it didn't, it would mean the gzip algo is defective, in fact.

You raise a valid point about reading zipped data into memory, especially if the data size is large. @g00se thanks. The primary reason I initially opted to read the data into memory is to simplify the handling and processing of the compressed logs. This approach allows me to manipulate the data easily before writing it to disk or performing any operations on it. I tried various ways but no luck.

Well it's important that you don't do that. Are you able to fix the real problem mentioned in my second comment?

As your shown code is not gzipping anything, it means the byte[] logData = sgtwService.fetchLogsFromMockService() is the one gzipping twice.
One possible explanation is that whoever wrote the mock thought it would have to mock the transport encoding gzip over http too.
Can you show the mock service code?

@user2023577's hypothesis is compelling. Whether mocking of gzip transport is behind or not though, you'd do well to make your method to retrieve the data return InputStream, then conceptually, the double-unzip would be something like try (GZIPInputStream outer = new GZIPInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(getLogAsStream()));OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("x.log"))) {outer.transferTo(out);}

Thank you for your follow-up, @g00se In my fetchLogsFromMockService method, I make a GET request to the mock service and expect to receive a byte array containing the log data

Nonetheless, I'd just call the hypothetical method with getLogAsStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(logData)); But of course you don't really want byte[] involved at all as it's memory-inefficient and could even cause problems

@user2023577 I've shared the complete code for my mock service in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/KAILASH08/b28c5c916e6842afe5852cac6cee682b

This is not a mock; It's a real http client connecting to some server. I thought you'd be showing the code that generates mock content on client side. As this is remote content, then shift the attention there. Hopefully you can turn any TLS off and sniff plain http on the wire with wireshark or tcpdump to passively find exactly what is being sent (it would have been my 1st suggestion if I knew it was real http). I think I'll let go now. It's obviously a proprietary code setup issue you can debug.

@user2023577 : Thank you for your feedback! I appreciate the clarification regarding the mock service. I will definitely take a closer look at the mock service code and the data being sent. Your suggestion to use Wireshark or tcpdump to inspect the HTTP traffic is also very helpful. I’ll keep you updated on what I find. Thanks again for your assistance!

It would probably be simpler to just dump the response to a binary blob and then inspect it. You can also use it to test any code (such as that I posted)

Thank you all for your insightful comments and suggestions regarding the issue I am facing with my Spring Boot application.
After reviewing the feedback, it seems that the root cause of the problem lies within the mock service that is generating a tar archive of the logs instead of a single log file. This explains why I was encountering a GZIP file containing another GZIP file when I attempted to save the logs.
To address this, I have modified my code to first extract the log files from the tar archive before attempting to decompress them. Here’s the updated code snippet that implements this change:
// Check if the fetched log data is valid
if (logData == null || logData.length == 0) {
    model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "No log data retrieved. Please check the selected log files.");
    return "downloaded_sgtw"; // Redirect to a result page with an error
}

// Specify the directory where you want to save the file
String destinationDir = "C:\\sgtw\\downInternal";

// Extract the log files from the tar archive
try (TarArchiveInputStream tarInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(logData))) {
    TarArchiveEntry entry;
    while ((entry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            continue;
        }
        String fileName = entry.getName();
        String destinationPath = Paths.get(destinationDir, fileName).toString();
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath)) {
            IOUtils.copy(tarInputStream, fileOutputStream);
        }
        successfullyDownloadedFiles.add(fileName);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Error occurred while downloading logs: " + e.getMessage());
}

This code effectively extracts each log file from the tar archive and saves it in the specified directory. I appreciate the suggestion to inspect the HTTP response, as this helped me understand that the data being returned was not in the expected format.
Thank you again for your assistance! If there are any further improvements or considerations to make, please let me know.

That's an important distinction, but your code still suffers from the same 'in memory problem'. Also, you don't need 3rd party packages to copy the tar stream, just: Files.copy(tarInputStream,  Paths.get(destinationDir, fileName));

@g00se Thank you for your valuable feedback! I appreciate your insight regarding the in-memory problem and your suggestion to use Files.copy() for handling the tar stream.
I’m always looking to improve my code, so if you have any specific recommendations or best practices for managing large files without loading everything into memory, I would love to hear them.
Thanks again for your help!!

Yes - just don't ;) Use a stream and write it straight to disk
